# Kubernetes ingress-nginx call service from non-default namespace

Tags: docker, kubernetes, prometheus, nginx-ingress

I have 3 services in my ingress, the first 2 use `default` namespace. The third service is **prometheus-server** service which has namespace `ingress-nginx`.
Now, I want to map my prometheus DNS to the service, but getting error because ingress can't find the prometheus service in `default` namespace.

How to deal with non-default namespace in ingress definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to create a new `Ingress` in namespace `ingress-nginx` that would route your DNS to that service. For example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  rules:  
  - host: your.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: prometheus-server
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Is it okay if I have 2 ingresses in one Node?

Comment: Yes it is OK. I have multiple ingresses on my cluster.

Comment: But, I just have one worker node, and the 2nd ingress would be deployed on that node too.

Comment: Note that ingress is different from ingress-controller. It is just a config, instead of a working pod.

Comment: Okay, let me try. And for the prometheus-server, I should change the serviceType from `NodePort` to `ClusterIP`, is it right?

Comment: Yeah, it works now. But the default yaml definition from prometheus use NodePort instead. Is it okay if I let it become NodePort rather than ClusterIP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188466/discussion-between-fei-and-justinus-hermawan).

Answer (score 3):

You will need to refer to your service in the other namespace with its full path, that is `prometheus-server.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local`.

You shouldn’t need a second Ingress to do this.

Comment: Might I ask why a second ingress would cost money? It is not a running pod, it is just a configuration. There is only one ingress-controller running in my understanding.

Comment: Ingress tends to allocate external resources, such as a [HTTP Load Balancer on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer). Having 1 of those is enough trouble, couldn't imagine having 2.

Comment: Ingress is different from Ingress-controller ( Or HTTP Load balancer ). There could be a setup that only has one ingress-controller ( HTTP Load balancer ) but have one ingress for each namespaces. This would have a better separation between different namespaces for better management.

Comment: Actually, you can have as many ingress objects (even in the same namespace) as you want. They all will be combined by the ingress controller in one config. If you have several ingress controllers of different types (nginx,traefik,...), each of them will collect and combine all ingress object of the specific type (mentioned in an ingress annotation) from all namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the info - multiple Ingress just seems overkill for the OP here, but I can see it's a useful second answer for other hosting scenarios if folks want separated `Ingress` per namespace etc.